# I faced error library not found for lRNRangeSlider in react native while I am making build?

Tags: react-native, react-router, reactive-programming

current source code has been working fine in simulator. 
just faced issue when I will make the Ipa file.

Comment: install this library again

Comment: It's already there. it working fine in simulator

Comment: its working on both ios and android device

Comment: yes,it's working on both device.